# Postfix : 454 4.7.1 Relay access denied

Tags: postfix-mta, relay

I configured my mail server following mostly [Workaround](https://workaround.org/ispmail/) tutorial, on my server, named KS1.

I have a second server, named KS2, which hosts a [piwigo gallery](https://piwigo.org/).

When a user susbcribes to this gallery, piwigo sends an email. I'v configured my KS1 serveur as smtp host :

```
$conf['smtp_host'] = 'ks1.my.domain';
```

But the email is not sent :

```
Oct 10 11:37:48 ks1 postfix/smtpd[19090]: connect from ks2.my.domain[2001:1234::1]
Oct 10 11:37:48 ks1 postfix/smtpd[19090]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ks2.my.domain[2001:1234::1]: 454 4.7.1 <user@externail.domain>: Relay access denied; from=<piwigo@my.domain> to=<user@externail.domain> proto=ESMTP helo=<galerie.my.domain>
Oct 10 11:37:48 ks1 postfix/smtpd[19090]: disconnect from ks2.my.domain[2001:1234::1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=6/7
```

I'v added in main.cf, the KS2 ip4 and ip6 in mynetworks, but still rejected :

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 1.2.3.4 [2001:1234::1]/128
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination,check_policy_service unix:private/quota-status,check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-forbidden-users.cf
```

When I send an email with the same script, but to an existing user on KS1, email gets to the local mailbox, and the logs are the following :

```
Oct  8 20:24:58 ks1 postfix/smtpd[8685]: connect from ks2.my.domain[2001:1234::1]
Oct  8 20:24:58 ks1 postfix/smtpd[8685]: B35CA1A0062: client=ks2.my.domain[2001:1234::1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=localuser@my.domain
Oct  8 20:24:58 ks1 postfix/cleanup[8700]: B35CA1A0062: message-id=<4352cbac6dc0b6f72e586c170587eb99@galerie.my.domain>
Oct  8 20:24:59 ks1 postfix/qmgr[22162]: B35CA1A0062: from=<piwigo@my.domain>, size=1264, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  8 20:24:59 ks1 dovecot: lmtp(8731): Connect from local
Oct  8 20:24:59 ks1 postfix/smtpd[8685]: disconnect from ks2.my.domain[2001:1234::1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
Oct  8 20:24:59 ks1 dovecot: lmtp(localuser@my.domain)<8731><KNmUBXtZf18bIgAAwVE1rw>: sieve: msgid=<4352cbac6dc0b6f72e586c170587eb99@galerie.my.domain>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
Oct  8 20:24:59 ks1 postfix/lmtp[8706]: B35CA1A0062: to=<localuser@my.domain>, orig_to=<localuser@my.domain>, relay=ks1.my.domain[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.51, delays=0.38/0/0/0.13, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <localuser@my.domain> KNmUBXtZf18bIgAAwVE1rw Saved)
Oct  8 20:24:59 ks1 dovecot: lmtp(8731): Disconnect from local: Client has quit the connection (state=READY)
Oct  8 20:24:59 ks1 postfix/qmgr[22162]: B35CA1A0062: removed
```

I also have spf :

```
"v=spf1 a mx ?all"
```

What did I miss ?
If you need extra settings, or logs, please specify what you need to debug.

Regards